# Is it correct to say "have some fruit on New Year's Day for luck"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

In some Asian countries, they believe that if you do something on New Year's Day, you might do it more often through out the year as good or bad luck.

For example, if you argue with your wife on New Year's Day, you might do it through out the year, which is a bad luck

If you eat vegetables and fruit on New Year's Day, you might eat them through out the year, which is a good luck because vegetables and fruit are good for health.

Is it correct for me to say to my children "**have some fruit on New Year's Day for luck**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically say "for *good* luck," since luck can be either good or bad. (By contrast, the adjective "lucky" refers only to *good* luck.)

So the correct phrase would be:

> Have some fruit on New Year's Day for good luck!